# What is the .interp section in an ELF and how do custom loaders work?

Tags: linux, elf, loader

ELF in Linux allows specifying a custom loader in the `.interp` header.  Usually, this is `ld`.  What are examples of non-ld loaders? What is used to load the loader itself?  Assuming I specify a non-ld interp, what is the interface it has to the executable it is supposed to load?

Answer (score 1):

> ELF in Linux allows specifying a custom loader in the .interp header. Usually, this is `ld`.

The loader usually depends on the `libc` being used, and is *never* `ld`.

On Solaris, it's usually `ld.so`.

On Linux it's usually `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` (on `i*x86` GLIBC systems), `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` (on `x86_64` GLIBC systems), etc.

> What are examples of non-ld loaders?

Musl-based systems [use](https://www.musl-libc.org/doc/1.0.0/manual.html) `$(syslibdir)/ld-musl-$(ARCH).so.1`

> What is used to load the loader itself?

The kernel does it. The loader must relocate itself, since there is nothing else which can do that.

> Assuming I specify a non-ld interp, what is the interface it has to the executable it is supposed to load?

That interface is *defined* by whatever `libc` you are using (which is why the loader and `libc` always come from the same package).

Answer (score 0):

> ELF in Linux allows specifying a custom loader in the `.interp` header. Usually, this is `ld`.

On Linux, that is normally `ld.so`, camouflaged as `ld-linux.so`:

```
$ readelf -p .interp /bin/gcc

String dump of section '.interp':
  [     0]  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

$ file /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: symbolic link to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
```